# is it possible to give the shadow inside the container?

Tags: html, css, shadow, box-shadow

```css
.part-two{
                float: left;
                height:300px;
                width: 200px;
                background-color:green;
                box-shadow: -10px -10px 1px red;
            }
```

```html
<div id="part-two" class="part-two">
                </div>
```

in the above code i have given an outer shadow using box-shadow property,instead of that i want to give the shadow on inside of the container,is it possible to give inner shadow using box-shadow method?if yes,how?
else ,is there any methods exists to giver inner shadow using css?

Comment: Yes it is possible using inset:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible to add `inner-shadow` to an element, you just need to add `inset` along with your `properties` in `box-shadow`.

> The presence of the inset keyword changes the shadow to one inside the
>   frame (as if the content was depressed inside the box). Inset shadows
>   are drawn inside the border (even transparent ones), above the
>   background, but below content.

```css
.part-two{
                float: left;
                height:300px;
                width: 200px;
                background-color:green;
                box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 10px 20px orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="part-two" class="part-two">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this **box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px 0px red inset;**

```css
.part-two{
                float: left;
                height:300px;
                width: 200px;
                background-color:green;
                box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px 0px red inset;
            }
```

```html
<div id="part-two" class="part-two">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

used to this

```
box-shadow:inset 5px 5px 1px red, inset 15px 15px 1px yellow;
```

`inset` as like this

```css
.part-two{
                float: left;
                height:300px;
                width: 200px;
                background-color:green;
                box-shadow:inset 5px 5px 1px red, inset 15px 15px 1px yellow;
            }
```

```html
<div id="part-two" class="part-two">
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

you looking for something like this?

```css
.part-two
{
float: left;
height:300px;
width: 200px;
background-color:green;
box-shadow: -10px -10px 1px red;
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px red;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px red;
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="part-two" class="part-two">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.part-two{
                float: left;
                height:300px;
                width: 200px;
                background-color:green;
                box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 1px red;
            }
```